# MEAN stack - Mongo output problems

Tags: mongodb, angular, mean-stack

I'm new to the MEAN stack

I'm following this tutorial - https://coursetro.com/posts/code/84/Setting-up-an-Angular-4-MEAN-Stack-(Tutorial)

I have everything installed.

When I run mongod I get

```
    2017-12-30T11:38:12.746+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
    2017-12-30T11:38:12.746+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
    2017-12-30T11:39:24.412+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58237 #1 (1 connection now open)
    2017-12-30T11:39:24.412+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:58237 conn: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.6.1" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "Mac OS X", architecture: "x86_64", version: "17.2.0" } }
```

Then in a different window I run mongo and get

```
    2017-12-30T11:38:12.737+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
    2017-12-30T11:38:12.737+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
    2017-12-30T11:38:12.737+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
    2017-12-30T11:38:12.737+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
    2017-12-30T11:38:12.737+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. 
    2017-12-30T11:38:12.737+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP 
    2017-12-30T11:38:12.737+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
    2017-12-30T11:38:12.738+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
    2017-12-30T11:38:12.738+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
    2017-12-30T11:38:12.738+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

In the browser window I see the 'app works' from Angular but I dont see output from mongo.

Do the outputs from mongod and mongo look correct, are the warnings from mongo something I need to fix.

Comment: output looks correct

Comment: Nothing to worry about in a development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log what i can say is mongo is installed Properly.

**Make sure your Node Server is running.**(Your node Server is not communicating with mongo)

Check Your node console or press F12 in browser and check Network Response.